# Apps in the kids category in IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

i have ceate app kids in unity3d and I've set parental gates in admob `TagForChildDirectedTreatment` to true in `AdRequest.Builder`.
apple store return error: Guideline 1.3 - Safety - Kids Category

You have selected the Kids category for your app, but it includes links out of the app or engages in commerce without first obtaining parental permission.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

> Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please update your app to add a parental gate before the user can leave the app or engage in commerce. You must also ensure that the parental gate cannot be disabled.

> Resources

For more information on parental gates, please review the Parental Gates resource page.

```
private AdRequest CreateAdRequest()
{
    return new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
            .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
            .AddKeyword("game")
            .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
            .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: Because of your app can contains some ads, link outs of your app, so you must add some screens that too complex with a kid, it make themself must get a help from their parent. `https://developer.apple.com/app-store/parental-gates/`

Comment: thank you, i have upload version 1 then ok. but when i upload version 2 i  have add banner show admob then error i have read document admob only add: TagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) but when upload apple store then error!!

Comment: because of you added your ads, that can effect to the kids. So you must to create some guide screen for make sure the kids has approved from their parents